# How to find a function with the following properties?

Tags: functions, special-functions

I want to find a function $f(s,x)$ such that

- $f(s,x)$ is analytic
- for any $s \in Z^+ $,
  $f(s,x)=B_s(x)$,
  where $B_s(x)$ are the Bernoulli polynomials
- $f(a, x)$ is elementary against $x$ at any constant $a$
- If possible, $f(s,b)$ is elementary against $s$ at any constant $b$

The last condition is not mandatory.